# Cordless blinds won't raise completely

Tags: blinds

I have one vinyl cordless blind that won't raise all the way.

To raise, you lift the bottom rail and the blinds go up.  About 3-4" from the headrail the blinds stop going up, every once in a while they'll go all the way up but it is a rare occurrence.

Is there an adjustment that can be made or a way to diagnose what exactly the issue is? I'd prefer not to replace them unnecessarily.

[image: cordless blind]

Comment: Yes there is adjustment, consult the manual

Answer (score 1):

Tension needs adjustment.

The adjustment of the roll up spring varies slightly from model to model.

At the end they all have some mean of adjusting the spring tension.

Since we do not know your model, here are some generic instructions.

Remove the blinds from the window.
Open the end caps. Here you will see a screw that if turned clockwise will increase the spring tension.

Comment: I'll give that a shot! Will update with brand/model if I can find it after taking it down.  Upvoted.